# JavaScript Unexpected end of input with a break

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, break

With this very simple code:

```
<body>
<script>
  var j;
  j=0;
  do {
    document.write("J="+j+" ");
    j++;
    if (j=4) {
      break;
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
```

I get an error: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input** just at the end of the script. This happens since I'm trying to use break to jump out from the loop.

Of course this is not the code I'm working on, which is way more complicated and needs the break jump. I know in this case a **do while** loop or **for** loop would have made it. This is just the smallest code I have showing the error.

Parentheses are balanced, braces are balanced, why does it say it is incomplete?

P.S. I have also tried this very same code as a function, receiving the error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }** on the brace that closes the function.

Comment: See answer below. Also, `if (j=4) {` should be `if (j==4) {`... `=` is assignment where as `==` comparison.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The = Vs. == point get obscured for me 'thanks' to the greater issue of the code not running. JS not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do` statements in Javascript expect a corresponding `while` expression.

E.g.

```
  var j;
  j=0;
  do {
    document.write("J="+j+" ");
    j++;
    if (j=4) {
      break;
    }
  } while (true);
```

Also worth noting, `if (j=4)` is always true in JS, you probably meant `===` for comparison instead of `=` for assignment. (as Adriani6 mentioned in the comments)

Though, if this is the complete example you're working with, then it would be cleaner to remove the if condition and break as such:

```
  var j;
  j=0;
  do {
    document.write("J="+j+" ");
    j++;
  } while (j !== 4);
```

or even easier to read:

```
for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
   document.write("J="+j+" ");
}
```

Comment: I already said this is not the complete code I'm working on, so the latter codes don't help me (to my real problem), but It seems you made the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (j=4) {
      break;
    }
```

it should be j==4

Comment: Should actually be `j === 4` ;)

Comment: Well yes is more restrictive, also compares the type